# atlbase.h compiler error :- cannot convert parameter from 'bool' to 'LPWSTR'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to port a VC++ application which worked on VS 2003 to VS 2010.
In one of the projects, after converting to VS2010 format, while compiling I get following error in atlbase.h:-

```
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(5137):
error C2664: '__noop' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'bool' to 'LPWSTR'
```

The line in question is :-

```
ATLENSURE(data.hEvent != NULL);
```

I am building for Unicode char set although I have also tried Multi-byte but in vain.

I have tried figuring this out and searching on relevant forums but no luck yet.
Any help is appreciated, please feel free to ask for more details.

**EDIT**
After seeing the comment below, I tried commenting this line and the error now occurs at line no 747 in atlbase.h which is 
ATLASSUME( m_p == NULL );
If I comment even this then same error occurs somewhere else (in a different file in fact).
I obviously can't modify atlbase.h, Does anyonw have any idea for resolving this?

Comment: Are you sure that the you are posting the correct line ?

Comment: I think I am, I can match the line number from error(5137). Also double-clicking the error message takes me to this line.

Comment: Try commenting the ATLENSURE to check that it's that line that is giving you the error.

Comment: How big is the application? If possible, try creating new VS10 projects from scratch, instead of going through the upgrade wizard. MS adds a few "unusual" options when upgrading, which sometimes causes problems

Comment: Jalf, it's very big and creating from scratch is not an option.

Comment: two hints:
1. Always check the very first error you see in output
2. Make sure that all include directories for your project are correct, ie. you are not including some include directorires for previous VS

Comment: It sounds like somebody has overridden the `__noop` intrinsic. The `__noop` intrinsic accepts all parameter types, but somebody overrode it with a version that accepts only `LPWSTR`. Check your preprocessor output.

Comment: ATLENSURE can be defined to __noop in release build, it should accept any parameter. At least this is what MSDN says

Answer (score 0):

Please try to build with "no-set" option for your project and all projects it's dependent on, it could help.